# Differentiate between albums and images in Imgur gallery

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, imgur

First of all, apologies as this is quite a narrow topic so I understand if it is removed. Imgur links come in several formats, as below:

```
http://i.imgur.com/kMoI9Vn.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/f7VXJQF
http://imgur.com/S1dZBPm
http://imgur.com/a/liD3a
http://imgur.com/gallery/HFoOCeg
```

In the Imgur API docs, there are relevant two endpoints. One for [albums](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album) and the other for [images](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image). Normally, there is no issue distinguishing between an image, and an album as album URLs are prefixed with `/a/`.

However, the following are both valid gallery URLs:

```
http://imgur.com/gallery/HFoOCeg
http://imgur.com/gallery/clWTb
```

The first is an image, and the second is an album. The [gallery](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery) category has two relevant endpoints, [image](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#image) and [album](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#album). Trying to use submit a request for an album to the image endpoint and vice versa results in a 404 error.

Is there any way when provided with just the ID (eg: `HFoOCeg`) to determine if it is an album or image without sending multiple requests?

Comment: Wondering the same thing.  As far as I can see, the album ids are 5 characters long, and the image ids 7.  But I don't know if this is consistent.  Did you find a good answer?

Comment: OP, were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ajax, you might find this helpful.  It picks through the data from https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/{hash} and puts a condition in the success function to distinguish an album from a single image.  So far it seems to work.  Incidentally, re my comment above, I have found out that album and image ids are not consistently 5 and 7 chars long respectively.

Grab the hash from a url like https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAznF.jpg whatever way you like.

Then:

```
var thehash = 'vTTHZ';
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/" + thehash,
      dataType: "json",
      headers:{
      'Authorization':'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      success: function(data) {
       if(data.data.is_album === true) {
        var dlength = data.data.images.length;
        for(i=0; i < dlength; i++) {
         $('#mydiv').append('<li>' + data.data.images[i].link + '</li>');
         } 
       } else 
       {
        $('#mydiv').html('<li>' + data.data.link + '</li>');
       }      
        console.log(data);            
      }
    });
```